# How to differentiate between scrolling with the finger and scrolling by tapping the status bar?

Tags: javascript, ios, prototypejs, mobile-safari

I'm making a webpage for iOS. I would like to perform an action when the user scrolls to the very top of the page via tapping the status bar (a shortcut). I don't want to perform this action when the page is scrolled to the top via using finger swipes.

So far, I have this code, which will wrongfully get triggered in both cases:

```
Event.observe(
    window,
    "scroll",
    function(event) {
        if (window.scrollY <= 0) {
            alert("You are at the top of the page, but I don't know how you got here");
        }
    }
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since this code is triggered after tap event, you can set a flag on that tap event which you can check later in this scroll event capture

```
Event.observe(
    window,
    "scroll",
    function(event) {
        if ( !flag )
        {
           if (window.scrollY <= 0) {
            alert("You are at the top of the page, but I don't know how you got here");
           }
        }
        flag = false;
    }
);
```

This flag is set when you tap on that status bar

Comment: The status bar resides outside of the webpage. How would I attach a click listener on it?

Comment: Sorry, then may I am not understanding correctly. Which status bar is in question here? Can you please post a pic?

Comment: @gurvinder372 If I understand correctly, the status bar that he or she is referring to is the grey bar at the top of the Safari on iOS that shows your carrier (on iPhones), the time, as well as battery level and other icons.

Comment: That is correct. The bar is part of the operating system, not the website.

Comment: In that case, I don't think you can capture that event as such and differentiate.